# WARN com.epam.healenium.client.RestClient - Failed to make response of 'getLastHealingData' request

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, self-healing, healenium

**Healenium Web version**
3.3.1

**Healenium Backend version**
healenium/hlm-backend:3.3.0

**Selenium version**
4.8.0

**Platform**
Java

**healenium.properties file**

```
recovery-tries=1 
score-cap=0.7 
heal-enable=true 
serverHost=localhost 
serverPort=7878 
imitatePort=8000
```

**Logs appeared during using Healenium**

Trying to heal...
[main] WARN com.epam.healenium.client.RestClient - Failed to make response of 'getLastHealingData' request.
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:7878/...